# Memory accessibility

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, exception, memory

For begin, i am learning WIN32 atm. So, i decided to find some guides on net. I found few articles about it, but at 4th article teacher wrote some code, that occured an exception, which stopped process and wrote: "This line called a breakpoint". This code used some memory actions (GlobalAlloc, GlobalFree) and some Font actions, which, i think, could occur some memory lackness. I thought, that if i will delete this code i delete this problem as well. But now my code can't run and here is some error always happening saying: "Access vialation at adress 0xcccccccc". This message appears at RegisterClassEx() line I have no knowledge to understand, which memory zone i should free. Tell me guys, what am i supposed to do. I use VS17 and Windows 10. Here is my code, wrote by hand (not necessary):

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>
LPCWSTR szClassName = L"defaultWindow";
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure(HWND hWindow, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, 
LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
        MessageBoxW(hWindow, L"Hello!", L"Program", MB_OK | 
        MB_ICONINFORMATION);
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(NULL);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProcW(hWindow, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return NULL;
}

int WINAPI _tWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE pInstance, LPTSTR 
lpszCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    WNDCLASSEX windowClass;
    windowClass.cbSize = sizeof(windowClass);
    windowClass.cbClsExtra = 0;
    windowClass.cbWndExtra = 0;
    windowClass.style = CS_VREDRAW | CS_HREDRAW;
    windowClass.hIcon = LoadIcon(hInstance, IDI_WINLOGO);
    windowClass.hCursor = LoadCursor(hInstance, IDC_ARROW);
    windowClass.hIconSm = LoadIcon(hInstance, IDI_WINLOGO);
    windowClass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(BLACK_BRUSH);
    windowClass.lpfnWndProc = WindowProcedure;
    windowClass.lpszClassName = szClassName;

    if (!RegisterClassEx(&windowClass))
    {
        MessageBoxW((HWND)NULL, L"Window class couldn't be registered!", 
         L"Error!", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
         return NULL;
     }

     HWND hMainWindow = CreateWindowW(szClassName, L"Программа", 
     WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 
     CW_USEDEFAULT, 
     (HWND)NULL,
        (HMENU)NULL, hInstance, (LPARAM)NULL);

    if (!hMainWindow)
    {
         MessageBoxW((HWND)NULL, L"Window couldn't be 
         created!",L"Error!",MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
         return NULL;
    }

    ShowWindow(hMainWindow, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hMainWindow);

    MSG message;

    while (GetMessageW(&message, hMainWindow, (UINT)NULL, (UINT)NULL))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&message);
        DispatchMessage(&message);
    }
    return message.wParam;
}
```

Guys help, i can't code

Comment: An exception and a breakpoint are unrelated things.

Comment: This seems to be a good time to [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). More specifically, use a debugger to catch the crash *in action* to locate when and where in your code it happens. Then you will also be able to examine the values of all involved variables.

Comment: the thing is, i din't put the breakpoint

Comment: i used debugger, but i think, the problem had attached to some system file or memory zone, because restarting vs, computer can't fix that, and my code i OK

Comment: i forgot. The problemm appears at Class REgistration line

Comment: Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Also please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/), and all of http://idownvotedbecau.se/ to learn some reasons your question might be down-voted.

Comment: You didn't initialize `windowClass`, try `memset(&windowClass,0,sieof(WNDCLASSEX))`

Comment: When you see something recognizable in an address, like "Access violation at address 0xcccccccc", that address may mean something. According to [the Wiki page on magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)), 0xcccccccc may mean you've marched off the end of what's been used in the stack or simply have an uninitialized pointer..

Comment: It automcatically initialyzed, because no errors occured when tried to define variables. The problem was about variables i din't initialyze

Comment: Upper answer was useful and, think helpful, if i wouldn't find a problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never initialize windowClass.hInstance or windowClass.lpszMenuName and so they have whatever random values happen to occupy the memory.
If you change the line:

```
WNDCLASSEX windowClass;
```

to

```
WNDCLASSEX windowClass {};
```

Those members would be zero-initialized.

Comment: thanks man, already got it, but if i wouldn't find it, it would help me much

Answer (score -3):

So, i finally recognized, that i forgot to add lpszMenuName and hInstance. Sorry, for wasting time xD